# Inject controllers that implements an interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

In ASP.NET Core MVC all classes that implement `Controller` will be automatically resolved and added to the MVC pipeline. These controllers can also be injected into the DI container using `services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();`

I also have a controller that also implements a specific interface, which I can also add to the DI container: `services.AddSingleton<IMyInterface, MyImpl>();`

```cs
public class MyImpl : Controller, IMyInterface { }
```

However, becase this controller also implements `Controller` it has already been added in `AddControllersAsServices()` so adding it to the DI container one more time causes there to be two instances of this class.

The reason for this design is that I will have multiple implementations of `IMyInterface` and later need to decide which one to use, but each implementation will also need to be a controller in order to provide certain API endpoints (each controller will provide different endpoints, so there will be no conflicts there).

How can I ensure that only one instance of my class is instantiated, and how can I then get all implementations of `IMyInterface`?

Comment: Why are you even doing this anyway? There's no reason you should be injecting controllers elsewhere.

Comment: Why not ditch the interface and create a controller for each class you would have implemented. Provide the specific routes for each controller and protect it with a filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as Im concerned Controller class is instantiated on each request, so even if you specify something like this (Ninject style):

```
services.Bind<IMyInterface, MyController>().To<MyController>().InSingletonScope();
```

It will be very bad. I mean, Controller is statefull, and you just mix everything up and breaking it's internal context.
What you might do is decorate through controller, instead of managing its lifetime yourself:

```
public class MyImpl : IMyInterface
{
}

public class MyController : Controller
{
     private readonly IMyInterface _inner; //delegate implementation to this one.
     public MyController(IMyInterface inner)
     {
         _inner = inner;
     }
}
```

And injection:

```
services.Bind<IMyInterface>().To<MyImpl>().InSingletonScope();//this is your logic.
sercices.Bind<MyController>().ToSomethingWhatever();//this line is managed by ASP .NET, mentioned this only to show the idea
```

Comment: I've read that controller classes are instantiated on each request. I've done a lot of debugging with my controllers and I've only ever seen them instantiated once (constructor is called only once for multiple request). Of course, this doesn't mean it will eventually be GC'ed and instantiated again, though... but maybe it lessens your concern :)

Comment: Controllers as singletons is a **really** bad idea.

Comment: @GTHvidsten This is really strange. It was probably configured somewhere in DI framework or you configured it to behave like this. Either way, it should not be scoped further than in per-request scope. Do you somehow override controller factory?

Comment: @eocron Now that I've given it some more thought, I've basically come to the same conclusion you have: Of splitting the controller to its own class. It looks like you might have an error in your code. The Controller isn't really supposed to implement `IMyInterface`, is it?

Comment: Yeah, it is. Will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You might need remove the MyImpl inheriting from Controller class. Also you need to consider MyImpl as sevice rather than Controller.

Another option is that this can be achieved with IoC container like Autofac or Ninject or Castle Windsor. When using with Autofac it will be something like the below

1. Add the Autofac, Autofac ASP.Net MVC4 Integration using NuGet Package
2. Open GLobal.asax.cs
3. Make following changes in the Application_Start(). 
   3a. Comment out the below code as

   //WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

3b. Create a new method RegisterAutofac(), call this as the first method call inside Application_Start()
3c. Below with the sample implementation for RegisterAutofac() method

```
private void RegisterAutofac()
{
    var builder = new Autofac.ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    builder.RegisterSource(new ViewRegistrationSource());

    // The object to be injected in constructor etc.
    builder.RegisterType<MyImpl>().As<IMyInterface>().SingleInstance();
    var container = builder.Build();
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
}
```